# Fopen "HTTP request failed" in production but works locally

Tags: php, apache, curl, phantomjs, guzzle

I am running PHP code on my local testing server (WAMP) as well as running it on a production server on Digital Ocean, OS Debian 8. Both have the exact same code base. I am getting an error on production server from function fopen() when using Guzzle.

> Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://www.thisismyserver.com):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

My error in more detail, the stack trace is even longer than this though:

> RequestException in RequestException.php line 51: Error creating
>   resource: [message] fopen(http://www.thisismyserver.com): failed to
>   open stream: HTTP request failed!
>
> [file] filepath/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php [line] 406
>
> in RequestException.php line 51
>
> at RequestException::wrapException(object(Request), object(RingException)) in RequestFsm.php line 103
>
> at RequestFsm->__invoke(object(Transaction)) in RequestFsm.php line 132
>
> at RequestFsm->GuzzleHttp{closure}(array('status' => null, 'body' => null, 'headers' => array(), 'effective_url' => 'http://www.thisismyserver.com', 'error' => object(RingException))) in FulfilledPromise.php line 25

So this line fails:

```
$resource = fopen($url, 'r', null, $context);
```

I am using Guzzle for the request. It seems that fopen is failing the HTTP request in production environment but success on local environment. Additionally, fopen is making a request to the production server in both cases. Because the code base is the same, and the request URL is the same (my production server) it must be a matter of configuration of fopen, PHP 7.0 or Apache2. But I cannot figure out what it might be. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: What `curl http://www.thisismyserver.com -v| head -20` returns when you run it on the server?

Comment: Can you `fopen` any other sites or files while in production?

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius Yes I can, I'm actually sending some parameters with the request to my server after ? in the URL, like http://www.thisismyserver.com?url=someurl. And the response contains website code (like HTML). This error is not persistent, and seems to be caused by some responses (with some URL parameters) but not all. Basically the production server is making web requests to a few different websites. And the production server subsequent web requests always succeed (no problem there).

Comment: @AlexBlex The response is part of the HTML doc that (it does not complete/close </HTML>) I want (stops at <noscript> tag) plus this message:  * Failed writing body (186 != 5559)
* Failed writing data
* Closing connection 0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (186 != 5559)

Comment: Additional info: I am using PhantomJs for the subsequent (stage 2) web requests. But those requests have no issues. Only the production server internal web request fail from Apache/PHP to PhantomJs.

Comment: The CURL 23 error came from limiting the Head to write 20 lines only. So that wasn't the issue. Still don't know what is causing this. It is very weird because the production to production server calls work for some URLs on a domain per above, but not all. For test to production server calls they ALL work.

Comment: Couldn't figure this one out. The problem is that "HTTP request failed" for some but not all server internal HTTP-requests, randomly. This problem has to do with how the server works or how fopen works, but I don't understand why. Debug not possible beause the error from fopen didn't give any more info than already provided in this question. My solution instead was to use require(); in the script for that script, as opposed to making a server internal HTTP-request. Perhaps I should have done that to start with.

Comment: Having same error.. Did you find the solution? @alieninlondon

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't.